# Add UV Mapped texture coordinates to OBJ file?

Tags: texturing, uv, export

I'm working on an OBJ parser for a game engine I am creating. I have the model being loaded correctly and all, but I've never really used blender before and I'm not entirely sure how to get my UV Mapped texture into the OBJ file. Inside the OBJ file, lines typically start with "v", "vn", and "f" for me, which seems normal. However, I saw someone who had lines starting with "g" that indicated texture coordinates in his OBJ file. Does anyone know how I could do this? I already have the texture mapped and everything, I just can't understand how I am supposed to get it into the exported OBJ file.

Comment: Blender exports this automagically... Lines starting with `vt` indicate texture coordinates (UV), and faces defined in the format `f 1/1 2/2 3/3` are faces with an UV map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want texture coords when exporting to `.obj`, make sure you have *Include UVs* ticked in the exporter options (it should be checked by default). Also, make sure that you actually unwrapped the model, check *UV Maps* under *Data* in the *Properties* panel to make sure that a UV map is assigned to your object.

[image]

If you should open an obj file you should see something like

```
vt 0.000100 0.000100
vt 0.999900 0.000100
...
f 1/1 2/2 4/3 3/4
```

where the lines with `vt` are texture coordinates and the line(s) with `f` specify faces that are a part of the UV map. Read more on the obj format [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#File_format). That being said, it is an open format and people might roll their own custom exporters and importers and name these identifiers differently (not recommended). I know that `g` is used by default for groups so you might be looking in the wrong place, also if you have a texture with the model make sure their is a `.mtl` file along with the obj to ensure that everything works correctly.

Comment: How do I find these particular settings to tick (Apply Modifiers / Include Edges / ...)  in Blender? This is what I'm looking at RN https://i.imgur.com/xd3mgdI.png

Comment: @TobiasKolb Press T to open the shelf with the options.

Answer (score 2):

Minimal example to include texture coordinates / vt in OBJ format:

1. File -> New
2. Change from Object Mode to Edit Mode
3. Click Shading / UVs from the upper left vertical aligned tabs
4. Under UV Mapping, change from Unwrap to Cube Projection under
5. Export to OBJ

Conclusion: The key to include vt in OBJ is step 4. Step 4 is only available in Edit Mode.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set Cube Projection. You can also use Unwrap, as long as you choose something under UV. It depends on how you're mapping.